# Vault backend storage migration from s3 to dynamodb

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, hashicorp-vault, hashicorp

I am trying to migrate vault storage from s3 bucket to dynamodb . The new vault ha cluster is in kubernetes

vault-2 1/1 Running 0 10s
vault-1 1/1 Running 0 15s
vault-0 1/1 Running 0 15s

I have used the below command to migrate the vault storage backend

```
vault operator migrate -config ~/Desktop/migrate.hcl
```

```
MacBook-Pro vaultconfig % cat ~/Desktop/migrate.hcl
storage_source “s3” {
bucket = “db-vault-cluster”
}
storage_destination “dynamodb” {
region = “us-east-1”
access_key = “***"
secret_key = "”
table = “demandbase-vault”
}
```

migration completed successfully, but was not able to view the secrets. When I restarted the pods, vault is not coming up again. and getting the below error.

```
2022-02-05T11:46:56.787Z [INFO] core: loaded wrapping token key
2022-02-05T11:46:56.803Z [INFO] core: successfully setup plugin catalog: plugin-directory=""""
2022-02-05T11:46:56.821Z [INFO] core: successfully mounted backend: type=system path=sys/
2022-02-05T11:46:56.822Z [INFO] core: successfully mounted backend: type=identity path=identity/
2022-02-05T11:46:56.822Z [INFO] core: successfully mounted backend: type=cubbyhole path=cubbyhole/
2022-02-05T11:46:58.753Z [INFO] core: pre-seal teardown starting
2022-02-05T11:46:58.753Z [INFO] core: pre-seal teardown complete
2022-02-05T11:46:58.753Z [ERROR] core: post-unseal setup failed: error=“error fetching default policy from store: failed to read policy: decryption failed: cipher: message authentication failed”
```

can someone help me to migrate the storage backend ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the same `seal` stanza in your configuration? It looks like Vault finds the storage but can't decrypt it.

Copy the `seal` part of the original (S3) configuration to the new (DynamoDB) configuration.